# Azure data factory HDInsight on-demand cluster 'Unable to instantiate SessionHiveMetaStoreClient'

Tags: azure, hive, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory, azure-resource-manager

I'm deploying an Azure data factory by deploying an ARM template using Visual Studio, basically following [this Azure tutorial](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/data-factory/data-factory-build-your-first-pipeline-using-arm.md) exactly, step by step.

The template defines a data factory, with an Azure Storage linked service (for reading and writing source and output data), an input dataset and an output data set, an HDInsight on-demand linked service, and a pipeline which runs an HDInsight HIVE activity to run a HIVE script which processes the input datasets into an output data set.

Everything deploys successfully and the pipeine activity starts. However I get the following error from the activity:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: **Unable to instantiate**
>   **org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient**     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:445)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:619)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

I have found various posts such as [this one](http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2016/02/24/hdinsight-hive-metastore-fails-when-the-database-name-has-dashes-or-hyphens.aspx) and [this one](http://blog.olandese.nl/2016/03/06/hdinsight-error-with-external-metastore-unable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-metadata-sessionhivemetastoreclient/) suggesting the porblem is a known bug caused by a dash or hyphen in the HIVE metastore database name.

My problem is that using an ARM template to deploy an HDInsigh cluster on demand, I have no access to the cluster itself, so I can't make any manual config changes (the idea of on-demand is that it is transient, only created to serve a set of demands and then deletes itself).

The issue can be reproduced easily simply by [following the tutorial step by step](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/data-factory/data-factory-build-your-first-pipeline-using-arm.md).

The only possible glimmer of hope I have found is by setting the [hcatalogLinkedServiceName as documented here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/data-factory-compute-linked-services/), which is designed to allow you to use your own Azure SQL database as the hive metastore. However, this doesn't work either - if I use that property, I get:

> ‘JamesTestTutorialARMDataFactory/HDInsightOnDemandLinkedService’
>   failed with message ‘**HCatalog integration is not enabled for this
>   subscription.**’

My subscription is unrestricted, and should have all the features of Azure available. So now I'm completely stuck. It seems that currently, using Hive with on-demand HDInsight is basically impossible?

If anyone can think of anything to try, I'm all ears!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get in contact with the author of the tutorial on GIT - who contacted the Azure product team, and this was their response:

> ...this is a known issue with Linux based HDI clusters when you use
>   them with ADF. The HDI team has fixed the issue and will be deploying
>   the fix in the coming weeks. In the meantime, you have to use Window
>   based HDI clusters with ADF.
>
> Please use windows as osType for now. I have fixed the article in GIT
>   and it will go live some time tomorrow.

The tutorial I link to has indeed been changed to use windows instead of linux. I've tried this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I recently studied the tutorial, and revised the tutorial. Here is my version, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-create-linux-clusters-adf/.   I didn't see the error.  The Hive table name doesn't have hyphen. I think mine is a bit easier to follow.  I made a few minor changes on the template itself.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Hmm strange, it definately didn't work for me. See my answer - the Azure product team have recognised it as a known issue. Perhaps they have pushed out the fix already?